# Lookup column allow multiple values warning

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I am working in SP Online modern UI. On one of the libraries, after checking on "Allow multiple values" for a lookup column field, I am seeing below warning in red.

[image]

can someone assist, i have not seen such warning before, please share thoughts to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it. It just means any custom code you might have running against this list will break. If you have this, you need to update the code to support multi-value for that field.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Derek.